# c# excel cell format to hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, excel

I am having a problem while converting text into the format [hh:mm:ss].

When I double click, formatting is fixed and cell value is automatically aligned to the right.

I am using [SpreadsheetStreams.net] NuGet package to create an excel file.

Here what I have already tried:

  1.

```cs
writer.AddCell(TimeSpan.Parse(columnNames[i].ToString()))
```

  2.

```cs
Style test = new Style();

NumberFormat format = new NumberFormat(NumberFormatType.Custom);

format.Custom = "hh:mm";

test.NumberFormat = format;

writer.AddCell(TimeSpan.Parse(columnNames[i].ToString()), test) OR

writer.AddCell(columnNames[i].ToString(), test)
```

Please refer to this image:

[image]

How can I format the cell to [hh:mm:ss]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many solutions I found a way :
Create a Style object having a custom type like below :

```
Style timeStyle = new Style();
NumberFormat format = new NumberFormat(NumberFormatType.Custom);
format.Custom = "hh:mm";
timeStyle.NumberFormat = format;
```

Then pass this as the second parameter and first parameter as a day (in double)

```
writer.AddCell(TimeSpan.Parse(columnNames[i]).TotalSeconds / 86400, timeStyle );
```